# How to assert that Set has item with exact property with hamcrest

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, assert, hamcrest

i've been trying assert that my Set has collection with given property with hamcrest, using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166415/how-do-i-assert-a-list-contains-elements-with-a-certain-property), but i have :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)V
>     at org.hamcrest.Condition$Matched.matching(Condition.java:52)

imports:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasProperty;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
```

code:

```
assertThat(mySet, contains(hasProperty("id", equalTo("expectedId"))));
```

have You any ideas how to assert it well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you should try to let assertThat do the work for you.

```
Set<WhateverPropertyTypeYouAreUsing> expectedSet = Collections.singleton( ... create a property object with that id/value);

assertThat(mySet, is(expectedSet))
```

The restriction here: that assumes that your set contains only that one property value.

Otherwise, you can go for:

```
assertThat(mySet.contains(someProperty), is(true))
```

(probably with an additional message to better describe a failing assert).

Prereq: your property class should be implementing equals() in a reasonable manner.

Comment: i tought it won't work if I just initiate te same object in test and assert it's in my returned collection, because I tought it would compare if its the same object, if You know what I mean , but well, it works

`assertThat(mySet.contains(expectedValue), equalTo(true));`

thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach will be:

`assertTrue(mySet.contains(someProperty);`

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is fine. Your problem is probably due to some version conflict. By the way, you should be using Hamcrest's `assertThat` (`import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat`), instead of JUnit's.