# can hamcrest "hasItem" get few matchers?

Tags: java, unit-testing, hamcrest

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12167781/1065869)

```
assertThat( myClass.getMyItems(), contains(
    hasProperty("foo", is("bar")), 
    hasProperty("name", is("bar"))
));
```

and

```
  assertThat(logsFromWaze, hasItem(
                hasProperty("foo", is("bar")),
                hasProperty("name", is("bar"))));
```

how can it work?

doesn't `hasItem` expect one matcher as an argument and not a list of matchers?

Comment: There is no `hasItem()` in your code and the `contains()` that you posted accepts vararg parameters.

Comment: thanks, then how can I check if **at least** one item satisfies 2 matchers for example?

Comment: Did you have a look at  `hasItems()`?

Comment: It matches few items. I want to find one or more items that satisfies a list of matchers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `hasItem` matcher that accepts varargs, but you can combine both `hasProperty("foo", is("bar"))` and `hasProperty("name", is("bar"))` via `allOf` matcher:

```
assertThat(logsFromWaze, hasItem(
        allOf(
                hasProperty("foo", is("bar")),
                hasProperty("name", is("bar"))
        )
));
```

This test will succeed when a single pass over the examined `Iterable` yields at least one item that matches all of the matchers passed to `allOf`.