# Writing test in Java to make sure function is called with old and new list of values

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have code something like this:

```
public void testMe(List<SomeItem> someList) {
  someList.forEach(someItem -> {
    SomeItem newItem = someService.createModifiedVersion(someItem);
    someService.doSomethingWith(newItem);
    someService.doMoreWith(newItem, someItem);
}
```

I am having hard time to write test with `when` and then `verify` as I have to mock `createModifiedVersion` with a loop. Right now I have something like this:

```
when(someService.createModifiedVersion(Mokito.any(SomeItem.class)))
  .thenReturn(someNewItem1)
  .thenReturn(someNewItem2)
  .thenReturn(someNewItem3);
```

Which doesn't ensure `someNewItem<N>` will be return for nth `someItem` from `someItemList`.

What will be best way to test in this case if I want to verify for all list items

```
verify(someService).doSomethingWith(someNewItem<N>);
verify(someService).doMoreWith(someNewItem<N>, oldItem<N>);
```

Note:  represent nth element of the list

Any suggestion?

**Update** I guess I am asking how I can verify `doMoreWith()` is called with `newItem` and `someItem` as that is in loop.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  How do you work out which `someNewItem` you want to return, for each `SomeItem` that you pass?  I feel sure the answer is to write an `Answer` implementation - I'm just not sure what that implementation would do.

Comment: @DavidWallace I have updated the sample code and my question. Hope that clarify the doubt I am having with mocking and testing within loop.

Comment: maybe something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166415/how-do-i-assert-an-iterable-contains-elements-with-a-certain-property

Comment: Take a look at Argument capture. As long as doMoreWith(....) is public method you must be able to mock & capture the arguments. You can also use doAnswer() API to capture the arguments, maintain state (collect the argument) and assert later. http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.22/org/mockito/Mockito.html#captors

Comment: Thanks for the responses .. but what about the `when` part how I can say for specific `someItem`it will return specific `newItem`

Comment: Yes, you can, using an `Answer` implementation.  I can help you with this if you indicate exactly what you require the `Answer` implementation to do.  Alternatively, you can just use a whole bunch of `when` statements, with a different `SomeItem` object passed to each one (so `when(someService.createModifiedVersion(someItem1).thenReturn(newItem1);` `when(someService.createModifiedVersion(someItem2).thenReturn(newItem2);` and so on.